# Use result of an if statement as a variable

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I'm wondering if there's a way of using the **returned value of a method**, which is **checked by an if statement**, as a **variable** ***if it is not nil***.

I hope the code example below helps explain what I'm after.

Let's say I have a method that returns a `UIImageView`, `-(UIImageView *)imageViewExistsForID:(NSString *)viewID`. In a method somewhere else, I want to check if that imageView returns a value, and as it is conditional, use an if-statement, as such:

```
if ([self imageViewExistsForID:<VIEWID>]) {

// Use the returned imageView here

}
else {

// 'nil' was returned, so no need to use the result

}
```

Normally, I would declare a placeholder variable before the if-statement, such as:

```
UIImageView *returnedImageView = [self imageViewExistsForID:<VIEWID>];

if (returnedImageView) {
...etc
```

I'm simply curious to know if there is a way of passing the result from the method, when first checked by the if-statement, without having to store the result in a variable first, which would be more akin to:

```
if ([self imageViewExistsForID:<VIEWID>]) {

    UIImageView *imageView = if-statement-result 
    // ??? (i.e. don't call the method again [self imageViewExistsForID:<VIEWID>])

}
```

*Disclaimer: I am asking this purely from an intellectually curious angle, as this is obviously not an 'issue' that is stopping me from achieving anything in my code. I'm always keen to learn more about Objective-C as I don't consider myself well-read enough in it yet. Thanks to anyone who can let me know about this particular point - apologies if I'm being incomprehensible!*

Comment: Why do you care if it's stored in a temp first?

Comment: Like I said in my 'disclaimer', I'm simply curious as to if there is another way to do it. I'm glad I've received feedback as I'm purely interested in learning as much as I can about Objective-C syntax :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is not a way to use the result of the if-condition. You will have to declare a placeholder variable.

It is possible, and under certain circumstances even permissible, to initialize the placeholder inside the `if` statement

```
UIImageView *returnedImageView;

if ((returnedImageView = [self imageViewExistsForID:<VIEWID>])) {
```

Note the extra parentheses; using `=` instead of `==` is a common mistake so the compiler may issue a warning without wrapping the assignment in parentheses.

Comment: Thanks for your swift response :) - may I ask if it was intentional to put two semi-colons on the end of the first line? Thanks for the insight! - are you implying that it is *always* permissible when the variable has been declared? Or are there certain circumstances when a declared variable cannot be used in this way?

Comment: No, that was just a typo. And by "permissible" I meant stylistically; it's always grammatically correct. There are certain places where it's essentially expected (`while((c = getchar()) != EOF)`), but I'd say avoid it until you get enough experience to see when it's acceptable. Most of the time, it's preferred for conditions not to have side-effects.

Comment: But that scheme is no more efficient (possibly slightly less) than assigning the value before the `if`, and it's unnecessarily confusing.

Comment: @HotLicks yes, that's why I added "under certain circumstances," implying that it generally shouldn't be done unless one knows what one is doing.

Comment: Good to know, @Kevin, and I look forward to the day when I can see the preferred use-cases (if it ever comes!).

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to @Kevin's answer, there is one situation where something like what you describe is possible:

```
myVar = foo ?: bar
```

which is equivalent to:

```
if (foo) {
   myVar = foo;
} else {
   myVar = bar;
}
```

It can be a nice way of substituting a default value for a `nil` without adding too much waffle.